# How to use -F option while Burn bootloader for ATtiny 85 using Arduino IDE

Tags: attiny85, arduinoisp

I'm very new to Arduino. I tried programming Attiny 85 module using Arduino as ISP. It worked fine few times. after that i'm getting below error.

```
Device signature = 0x000000
avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
```

I understand that i can override this step using -F option. But really cannot figure out how to use -F option in Arduino IDE. Please Help!

Comment: don't use -F. solve the problem with wiring

Comment: i tried checking and changing jumpers multiple times. no luck.

Answer (score 1):

For what I know there is no easy way to pass custom options to `avrdude` via the Arduino IDE, but [Sloeber](https://sloeber.io) (to which I'm a contributor) does.

Beware though, the `-F` [option of `avrdude` command](https://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/user-manual/avrdude_4.html#Option-Descriptions) doesn't **solve** the problem, just forces to skip the device signature verification, but if your Attiny is returning such signature something else is wrong and you'll end up with a failed firmware upload anyway.

If the device was working and suddenly stopped it's more than probably a wiring issue, as already suggested in the comments. The second most probable cause, in my experience, would be a hardware issue: you might have accumulated some static charge and then touched the Attiny or any wire connected to it, destroying one of the ISP pins...

My bet is on the former: my experience with the latter is you get changing signatures in the form of `0xFFFF00`, `0x0000FF` and `0xFFFFFF` but, luckily for me, this didn't occur so often to accumulate a true knowledge.

Comment: Are you aware the Sloeber site is down (3pm EST 2018-12-28). There’s also a bad cert on the site